# very long build - ASP.MVC 2 in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm developing Asp.MVc 2 application. In solution i've about 10 projects and i have no idea why bulid takes so much time - ~5 minutes.

I've tried to unload some projects, but it saves mayby 15 seconds.

I'd like to try and learn TDD, but writing and running tests will waste 80% time.

I'm using VS2010 and default MSBuild - is there any way to improve speed of building applications? I don't know mayby other builder (NAnt could help?)

Comment: I've got a solution with 10 projects in at the moment in VS2010 and having an MVC2 UI and it builds within seconds. Have you added anything big into it recently? Have you got the source code for any frameworks included in the build to help with debugging?

Comment: I've only asp.mvc2 app and class libs projects and one WCF rest project. I;m using EF4 so mayby it is the main cause, i'll try move it to other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried separating your projects into logical solutions and not have them all in the same one? (I'm assuming you do).
There is just some code that doesn't change so often that you have to build it all the time.

Comment: Yep, breaking apart large solutions really helps with TDD. If you have any designer generated code (like DBML or EF files) put those in their own project if possible.

Comment: I'm using EF, so mayby it is good idea to move them. I'm also using TFS (2008 as i suppose), i don't know is it the cause, because we don't use TFS's builds, but mayby it slows down. Unfortunately i don't have privilages to play around TFS's config